# Paginate man pages

Tags: linux, solaris, man, text-formatting

Different systems render man pages differently. Some paginated the pages by default, some don't. How can I control the pagination behaviour?

And how can I configure the page height (in lines) when pagination is enabled?

For example, on Solaris 10, when I view man pages in the terminal (e.g. `man man`) they are paginated like this:

```
User Commands                                              man(1)
...
SunOS 5.10          Last change: 29 Apr 2010                    1

User Commands                                              man(1)
...
SunOS 5.10          Last change: 29 Apr 2010                    2
...
```

On Fedora Linux the same call just renders one big page:

```
MAN(1)                        Manual pager utils                        MAN(1)
...
2.7.6.1                           2016-12-12                            MAN(1)
```

Comment: On which system do you want to control this behaviour?

Comment: @Kusalananda, on Linux and Solaris.

Answer (score 2):

The groff documentation describes [several options](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Man-options.html#Man-options) that can be used to control pagination, including `-rCR=0` to disable the default single-page behaviour in nroff mode.  This can be set using the `MANROFFOPT` environment variable.

I haven't found a way to control the page length, short of injecting a `.pl` request into the nroff input stream, and in the absence of that it seems to be effectively a fixed value.  It might be worthwhile for `man` to gain an option to enable pagination and set the page length based on the terminal size ...

Comment: I found, for `tmac.an.old` and classic AT&T nroff, one can inject `.ch }H` and `.ch }F` after the initial `.TH` (perhaps with `.if \ng==1` so it can be triggered with `-rg1` from the command line) to the same effect; it will lose the last trailing footer as well, unlike what __mdoc__ (which already defaults to _cR_) does.